# Issue with Maven Artifactory Release Management with git/gerrit/TeamCity

Tags: git, maven, ssh, teamcity, gerrit

I'm trying to use the Release Management capabilities of the maven Artifactory plugin with git, gerrit and TeamCity.  The plugin works fine until it tries to push the release branch to git where I get the following error:

```
[21:30:29][Step 1/2] [RELEASE] Committing release version on branch 'v1.0'
[21:30:29][Step 1/2] [RELEASE] Creating tag 'v1.0.0-rc0'
[21:30:29][Step 1/2] [RELEASE] Pushing branch 'v1.0' to 'ssh://sys_user@git-company.com:29418/project.git'
[21:40:35][Step 1/2] Git execution failed: '[git, push, ssh://sys_user@git-company.com:29418/project.git, refs/heads/v1.0]'
[21:40:35]
[Step 1/2] org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitException: Git execution failed: '[git, push, ssh://sys_user@git-company.com:29418/project.git, refs/heads/v1.0]'
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitCmd.runCommand(GitCmd.java:68)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitCmd.launchCommand(GitCmd.java:29)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitManager.push(GitManager.java:117)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitCoordinator.afterSuccessfulReleaseVersionBuild(GitCoordinator.java:117)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.listener.AgentListenerReleaseHelper.runnerFinished(AgentListenerReleaseHelper.java:81)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.ArtifactoryAgentListener.runnerFinished(ArtifactoryAgentListener.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:121)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.runnerFinished(Unknown Source)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.runnerStages.finish.FireRunnerFinishedFStage.doFinishStage(FireRunnerFinishedFStage.java:29)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerFinishStagesExecutor.runFinishStage(RunnerFinishStagesExecutor.java:32)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerFinishStagesExecutor.doBuildFinishStages(RunnerFinishStagesExecutor.java:23)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.RunnerContextExecutor.safeCallFinishStages(RunnerContextExecutor.java:65)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.RunnerContextExecutor.callRunnerStages(RunnerContextExecutor.java:56)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.StepExecutor.processNextStep(StepExecutor.java:25)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeRunnerStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:138)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.runStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:123)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeBuildRunners(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:83)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.doBuildStage(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:44)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.doStages(BuildRunActionImpl.java:75)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.runBuild(BuildRunActionImpl.java:55)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:295)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:53)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:259)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.ProcessTimeoutException: Timeout exception: the process did not produce output longer than 600 seconds
    at jetbrains.buildServer.CommandLineExecutor.waitForProcess(CommandLineExecutor.java:191)
    at org.jfrog.teamcity.agent.release.vcs.git.GitCmd.runCommand(GitCmd.java:53)
    ... 32 more
```

The push command works fine on the command line from the TeamCity build agent (after I create the prerequisites) so I'm pretty sure the system is configured correctly.  The build agent is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I suspect the issue may be related to the agent's ssh keys (which are in the normal place, ~/.ssh) because I have had issues in the past where TeamCity agent appears to have trouble finding them.  Unfortunately, with no ability to see exactly why git is failing, it is difficult to confirm.  Anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong and/or how to get info out of this black box?

Comment: Does sys_user have permission to push to refs/heads/* and to create references?

Comment: Yes, user has correct permissions.  Like I tried to say, I tried it from the build agent account on the build agent.